# ConcurrentModificationException when saving entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Large REST web application based on Spring Boot, spring-data-jpa. I have `PersonEntity` which has ManyToOne relation with `ParentEntity`. Owner of relation is `PersonEntity` which has `parentId` in his table.

After executing many SoapUI concurrent test, we discovered that randomly in one place `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown (randomly, actually we saw that once and app is running more than one year, but I guess that we have some concurrent access from another thread)

Code where problem occurs:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void disconnectPersonFromParent(final String parentId, final String personId) {
    //throw NotFound when null from repo
    final PersonEntity personEntity = personService.getPerson(personId); 
    //throw NotFound when null from repo        
    final ParentEntity parentEntity = parentService.getParent(parentId); 
    if(parentEntity.equals(personEntity.getParent())) {
        personEntity.setParent(null);
        //Addresses comes from parent, when we disconnecting we have disconnect addresses also
        personEntity.setAddresses(new HashSet<>()); 
        personRepository.save(personEntity);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
||ERROR|http-nio-auto-1-exec-487|error|[TransactionSystemExceptionMapper:353]|Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:719)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:752)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntryIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:750)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.IdentityMap.entryArray(IdentityMap.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.IdentityMap.concurrentEntries(IdentityMap.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 131 more
```

Is it a problem with code? How can I avoid it?

Comment: You are right, PersonEntity instance was updated by another thread and saved to the DB. That's why you are getting this error. It may happen due to different reasons: row is locked, table is locked

Comment: Ok, but I ask how can I resolve that, what is best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a VERSION column to all the tables in the database and annotate that with @Version as below in the entity.

```
@Version
private Long version
```

Once version column in place JPA/Hibernate automatically checks the version prior to saving the entity. If there is a any version mismatch between the entity load and save, you will get javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException. You can catch the exception and take any necessary action like logging, notifying user, etc. We have various articles on the net regarding @Version implementation.

Hope it helps.

You can have a Exception handling in Service method around Repo call OR Add
a @COntrollerAdvice to capture exception and handle them in common. The example bellow is for all REST calls to send 500 error with "custom message" as the response.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(value = { Exception.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAllExcecption(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
    // Do what ever you want. Log the error message, send notification etc
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, logId.longValue(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            request);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean, that all repo operations should be in try-catch?

Comment: Your service method should have a try catch around the repo call. Or just throw the exception from Service class and you can have a common exception handling as below. Spring has @ControllerAdvice feature. This will handle all exceptions that comes from the Controller methods.

Comment: Hmm, I seek for solution when it will be waiting for resource rather then throwing exception, but I will think if I can use your answer